# Passing a Taxonomy term via URL to add content form a content type in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

How can I pass a content type Taxonomy term in the url itself when I have created one node using that content type?

Comment: Can explain more?

Comment: @ЕлинЙ.  Well, the self-accepted answer to that question is IMHO useless, because it just suggests you use the [Preopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module without saying how you do it.

Comment: @FreeRadical I still don't think it is a valid reason to duplicate questions. As far as I remember, if only answer was downvoted, nobody could vote duplicate? And if OP would say how he tried with populate and don't know how, it wouldn't be duplicate, but a follow-up question.

Comment: @FreeRadical you are right, that question might not have a good answer, but that doesn't make this question valid. It is still a duplicate of that function.

Comment: To quote from the close message: "This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, **please ask a new question**."  In this case, it is quite *obvious* that the answer given does not answer the question.  Nominating for repopening, so that it can be answered.

Comment: OK - it is closed, so it can't be answered properly, but here is the answer anyway: First, you need to download and enable the [Prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module. The syntax you use to prepopulate taxonomy terms with D7 is (AFAIK) not documented anywhere and it is also radically different from the syntax used in D6 that is demoed in a number of screencasts of the Preopulate module.  In D7 taxonomy terms are fields.  If you read the source code, you'll find that you prepopulate taxonomy terms as would any other field. (Continued in next comment).

Comment: (Continued from my previous comment.) I.e. if your taxonomy term field is `field_tags` and you want to prepopulate with the term "myterm", you use the following syntax (with clean URLs): `/node/add/article?edit[field_tags][und]=myterm`.

Comment: @Mołot I can see that there is use in letting a duplicate question get good answers, and then close the older question as duplicate of this one instead. If it means the site gets better answers, I think it's a good solution. :)

Comment: @FreeRadical In that case, the OP should make clear the question is not a duplicate: For example, the OP could say they tried the module suggested by that answer, but they were not able to use it because [explanation of the problems they met]. If it is just a matter of making an answer more complete, that doesn't require to ask a new question; it is enough to edit the existing answer or write a new answer more complete than the existing one.

Comment: @Letharion That is true, but we still don't want duplicate questions.